# How to Autonumber rows in AngularJS with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to AngularJS. Please forgive if the question is too simple. I have  a list which is displayed with ng-repeat with AngularJS. I am using bootstrap pager for paging which selects only 10 records at a time .

```
var start =0;
var end = 10;
results.slice(start, end);
```

I want to Autonumber the rows.

This is what i tried.

1. Used $index with ng-repeat .(This works good ,but the index gets repeated in second page)
2. used

{{sequenceId + 1}} (all numbers show 1)

I want the numbers to be showed in the table when the table loads.

Answer (score 0):

- The standard practice in pagination is to send the last index as part
  of the request and respond with the next index. So you can pass
  `$index` to your API and get it to respond with `$index +1`
- The other option is to store the index in some place, and use a
  filter like so:

  app.filter('startFrom', function() {
             return function(input, start) {
                 if(input) {
                     start = +start; //parse to int
                     return input.slice(start);
                 }
                 return [];
             }
         });

  {{item.Name}}
- Another option is (assuming that the entire set is available to you)
  to just add an index to your original data set. Add a continuous
  index as one of the keys in the array and display that list.

Answer (score 0):

What about something simple like

```
$index - start + 1
```